# Generate an url in javascript with dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How should I structure a function named `countryUrl()` taking the parameter `id` from the `<li>` tag in:

```
<ul>
  <li onclick="countryUrl(this.id)" id="20" value="Benin">
    <a href="#">Benin</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and concatenating it to `/frame/theme/`
in an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url :"/frame/theme1/"+myUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:  function(data) { ...
```

Would it be something like :

```
function countryUrl(id){
   return "/frame/theme/"+this.id; 
}
```

Then how do I pass it to the `url:` field ?

Comment: You have a link there, which is a perfect place to store a URL for jQuery to access. Also, don't use an inline `onclick` handler because JavaScript belongs in `.js` files not `.html` files.

Comment: So where is the function at that you are calling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use inline HTML event attributes, such as `onclick`. There are a [variety of reasons why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991). Instead, separate your JavaScript from your HTML and follow modern standards as shown below.

Next, although it is legal for an `id` to be a number, it's not a good idea (especially for backwards compatibility).

Additionally, `li` elements don't have a `value` attribute. Use **[`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)** attributes to store custom values in HTML elements instead.

Lastly, you don't need hyperlinks in your lists to make the list items clickable.

All you need to do is set up your `li` element(s) to have a `click` event callback and that callback extracts the data from the clicked `li` and  uses it as you need.

```js
// Get reference to the bullet:
var li = document.getElementById("lstBenin");

// Set up bullet to be clickable:
li.addEventListener("click", countryURL);

// function that is called when bullet is clicked
function countryURL(){

  // Create new URL based on the "data-value2" attribute
  // of the element that was clicked:
  var newURL = "/frame/theme1/" + this.dataset.value2;
  console.log(newURL);  // Test

  // Make AJAX call using new URL
  $.ajax({
          type:"GET",
          url :newURL,
          dataType: 'json',
          success:  function(data) { 
          }
        });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="lstBenin" data-value1="Benin" data-value2="20">Benin</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sorry, mouse gone wild may be :/ Thank you for your correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can you data("id") instead of id.
Then you will just use counrtyUrl(this.data('id').
In the $.ajax call use the argument from the function.